# Validate Uniqueness of Scoped to Join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given a few tables:

`products`
`prices`
`prices_regions`
`regions`

I'd like to ensure that a prices are unique for a region and a product. Is it possible to write this using a `validates_uniqueness_of` or does it require a custom validation?

For example:

```
laptop = Product.create(name: "Laptop")
tablet = Product.create(name: "Tablet")
brazil = Region.create(name: "Brazil")
canada = Region.create(name: "Canada")
mexico = Region.create(name: "Mexico")
Price.create(product: laptop, regions: [brazil, mexico])
Price.new(product: laptop, regions: [canada]).valid? # true
Price.new(product: laptop, regions: [canada, brazil]).valid? # false
Price.new(product: laptop, regions: [canada, mexico]).valid? # false
Price.new(product: laptop, regions: [brazil, mexico]).valid? # false
Price.new(product: tablet, regions: [brazil, mexico]).valid? # true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that custom validators are perfect for logic like this, you can make them as simple or complex as necessary, and it is easy to extend the logic later on. In this case it would look something like this:

```
# app/models/price.rb
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :regions, regions: true
  #...
end


# app/validators/regions_validator.rb
class RegionsValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each(price, _attribute, regions)
    if price_exists?(price, regions)
      price.errors.add(:regions, :uniqueness, message: 'must be unique')
    end
  end

  def price_exists?(price, regions)
    Price.where(product: price.product, regions: regions).present?
  end
end
```

EDIT

Sorry, to actually answer the question explicitly – you will need a custom validator. `validates_uniqueness_of` only validates the columns of the table in question (ie. `Price`).

Comment: For a simple "unique within a scope" validation, this is [built-in to Rails' validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) - you could do something like: `validates :price, uniqueness: {scope: :region}`. However, since in this case we are dealing with a joins table and more complicated logic, I agree that what you have described above is best.